# How to set song as ringtone WP 8

Tags: lumia, ringtone

Yesterday I bought a Nokia Lumia 520.

How do I set a song as ringtone in this device?

Steps that I followed:
1. Setting -> Ringtones+Sounds

Inside this setting, there is no option for to custom choose our favorite song as ringtone.

I searched previous questions that all are talking about windows phone 7 and i didn't get perfect answer for this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several restrictions that ringtones have on them and as such, you cannot just set any mp3 (or song). Even if you have one that meets the requirements as a ringtone, you also cannot add a ringtone straight from your music library.

```
If you can play a sound file on your phone, if it isn't protected 
with digital rights management (DRM), and if it's smaller than 30 MB,
then you can use it as a ringtone on your phone.
```

[According to Microsoft](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/start/add-ringtones-to-my-phone), you have to connect your phone to your PC and add the file to the ringtones folder. On your phone, go to Settings Settings icon > Ringtones + sounds > Ringtone. Your new ringtone will appear under Custom in the list of available ringtones.

You can also receive a ringtone via sms. Tap and hold on the file, and select save as ringtone.

Comment: I tried to move that music file into ringtones folder. But still it isn't showing the file. My friend who is having the same mobile saying that it will take time to detect that file. Is that So?

Comment: Try to set the Genre tag as ringtone. Also make sure it has no drm and if that still doesn't work, I only set files as ringtones that are under 30 sec.

Comment: Finally I set rington. Its 1.45Min long.

Comment: I have written a fully customized article on **[how to sett customized ringtones in lumia phones](http://www.windowappreviews.com/how-to-add-customize-ringtones-to-nokia-lumia-phones/)**. you can find in above link.

Comment: Side note: If you're using phone, that supports SD cards then, even if you set the phone to store most files on that SD card, you **must** copy `.mp3` files (your custom ringtones) to `Phone\Ringtones` folder. Placing them in `Ringtones` folder on your SD card won't work.

Comment: And, according to [this](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/9513/11237) (verified by me), your file must be no longer than 40 seconds, no bigger than 1 MB and **must** have `ringtone` value set as `Genre` in MP3Tag in order to appear in `Custom` section of Ringtones selection in any Lumia phone.

Answer (score 4):

If the song is already in your music library on your 520 then you can simply use <strike>Nokia</strike> [Ringtone Maker](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/ringtone-maker/9wzdncrfhvdm) (Free Download on WP Store). <strike>Nokia</strike> Ringtone Maker lets you choose a song and cut a 40 second segment then save as a ringtone. Then go to Settings > Ringtones & Sounds and select it from the ringtone list :)

**However, the song must be DRM Free!**

Answer (score 1):

I already have answered [here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/9504/no-custom-ringtones-on-lumia/13580#135).

You can use this method as I am using with my Lumia 535 effectively. This also works well for file sizes greater than 1MB.

1. Go to store and download UC browser app.
2. Download any song with UC.
3. Go to UC download list and select the downloaded file.
4. Tap on "Set as ringtone" and that's it.

Check this out. Its 100% working **for greater file sizes**.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Windows Phone SE. A word of advice, link only answers are not prefereed in the community. It is wise to add the solution or a short desc in this answer too. This is because links may get broken also it is not a good way to redirect users to another page for answers. Hope that you find this information useful.

Comment: @KolappanNathan linking to another answer within the same site is less frowned upon (although I'd typically suggest the more recent copy of the question instead be flagged as a duplicate, and the answers merged)

Comment: @RowlandShaw I agree. But having some details here would be good that just having an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Way i did to choose my own ringtone. This may be useful to others.

These are the steps i followed to make 
1. Connect your WindowsPhone to computer using Data Cable.

1. Copy the mp3 song that you want to make it as ringtone into ringtones folder.
2. Remove the Phone from Computer.
3. Restart(Switch Off then On) your mobile.
4. Goto Settings->Ringtones+Sounds -> Ringtones (Now you can see the Mp3 song that you copied to Ringtone folder.)

Comment: but i cant use my 2mb mp3 file as a rington for nokia lumia 525. i already copied it in rington folder

Answer (score 0):

Go to your app store and try this:

http://ringtone-maker.en.softonic.com/windows-phone-7

It is a product from publisher **Microsoft Mobile**. Its very useful with good quality, alerts. You can make any part or the full song as a ringtone here.

And most interesting part is that after creating the file here it will be shown in your **Settings->Ringtones+Sounds** library ay the same time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the file on a PC, right click mp3 file select "properties" select details tab at top, set(add/edit) genre as "ringtone"
2. move file to phone storage under "ringtones" folder
3. In `Settings/Personalization/Sounds/Ringtone` or search `Ring tones + sounds` the file name is now in the list of ringtones

Note: it does not appear under "custom" for me its just in the list