# wanted to use a mp3 file as ringtone lumia 520? Did not workout

Tags: lumia-520

1. First tried downloading directly from a website. Could only play not download.
2. Then tried to download it from gmail attachement. could only play not download.
3. Tried sending it by bluetooth from another phone. received the file. could not save or play.

Auto search by the phone for suitable apps states app not available.

Hence, how to download a mp3 file and use it as a ringtone.

Answers will be helpful.

Comment: @caschw The procedure for setting up custom ringtones is quite different on WP7...

Comment: I'm sorry meant to choose http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/how-to-set-song-as-ringtone-wp-8/2590#2590

Answer (score 3):

Download it on your computer and transfer it onto your phone into the ringtones folder.
Check out the official guide:
http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/add-ringtones-to-my-phone

Also, there might be some that can download mp3s and set them as ringtones, have a look in the store.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can download it via UC Browser, it gives the option to set the downloaded mp3 file as ringtone.

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy your files to your phone
2. Install [Ringtone Maker 8.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/store/apps/ringtone-maker-81/9wzdncrdxt4z) from the store
3. Use Ringtone Maker 8.1 to navigate to your mp3 songs and set them as
   ring tones.

I am doing the same thing for my Lumia 520.

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

I already have answered [here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/9504/no-custom-ringtones-on-lumia/13580#135). You can use this method as I am using with my Lumia 535 effectively. This also works well for file sizes greater than 1MB.

1. Go to store and download [UC browser app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/uc-browserhd/9wzdncrfj3kn).
2. Download any song with UC.
3. Go to UC download list and select the downloaded file.
4. Tap on "Set as ringtone" and that's it.

Check this out. Its 100% working for greater file sizes