# No Custom Ringtones on lumia

Tags: nokia-lumia-535, ringtone

I am using a Lumia 535. My phone is not showing any custom ringtones in spite of adding some music clips to the ringtones folder.

I am using Windows Phone 8.1. Please help

Comment: How did you put the music there? With a PC?

Comment: Once i was unable to select a song that copied directly from their Music folder into the Ringtone folder on the phone. All that was necessary was to copy the song onto laptop/PC before copying it back into the Ringtone folder it solved or if custom can try with Ringtone Maker app that could help.

Comment: Try to add ringtone files (for example. mp3 files) to the Ringtones folder by connecting your phone to PC using USB cable.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/2544/106

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, I would suggest you to try [Ringtone Maker](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/ringtone-maker/9wzdncrfhvdm). It worked fine for me.

Now, if you are using any other file, just take care of these restrictions:

- MP3 or WMA file,
- not protected with Digital Rights Management (DRM),
- less than 1 MB in size,
- less than 40 seconds in length,
- must have the genre "ringtone" set.

The file must be copied directly from a PC to the phone's Music or Ringtones folder. If your phone supports an SD card, then copy the file to the phone's root folder. Copying to the Ringtones folder on the SD card won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the info bro....How to add Ringtones of size greater than 1mb

Comment: The problem is you cant thats why make use of Ringtone Maker app to create your own custom ringtone of specific length. I have been using it hence recommended. Its a microsoft app so rest assured.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method as I am using with my Lumia 535 effectively. This also works well for file sizes greater than 1MB.

1. Go to store and download [UC browser app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/uc-browserhd/9wzdncrfj3kn).
2. Download any song with UC.
3. Go to UC download list and select the downloaded file.
4. Tap on "Set as ringtone" and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Copy the file on a PC, right click mp3 file select "properties" select details tab at top, set(add/edit) genre as "ringtone"
2. move file to phone storage under "ringtones" folder
3. In Settings/Personalization/Sounds/Ringtone the file name is now in the list of ringtones

Note: it does not appear under "custom" for me its just in the list